# Multi-threading on wxHaskell

Tags: multithreading, haskell, wxhaskell

Has anyone used multi-threading ***safely*** in *wxHaskell*? I am trying to determine if a *wxHaskell* program could use multi cores to do background processing.

The link below explains how to do this safely in *Gtk2Hs*:

http://dmwit.com/gtk2hs/

The key seems to be to only make GUI library calls from the main thread, which is always OS-bound, so other threads will need to find a way to request the main thread to make a GUI library call for them, rather than do a direct GUI library call themselves. In *Gtk2Hs* this is done using *postGUIAsync* or *postGUISync*, but I have not found anything online on how to do this in *wxHaskell*.

Is there any equivalent *postGUI* in *wxHaskell*, or do I need to roll my own, assuming this is possible?

Also, if I follow the overall approached described above for *Gtk2Hs* multi-threading, would I be able to safely multi-thread in *wxHaskell*?